# Find column index by using value in column dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this dataframe:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
b <- c(110, 90, 200, 330, 250)
c <- c(120, 350, NA, 400, 240)
d <- c(180, 200, 120, 240, 340)
e <- c("2019_12", "2020_01", "2020_01", "2020_02", "2019_12")
df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d,e)
names(df) <- c('id', "2019_12", "2020_01", "2020_02", "X")
```

I want to find the column index by using column X. For example if column X has the value "2020_01", so the column index would be 3.

The result I want should be like this;

```
  id 2019_12 2020_01 2020_02       X  col_index
1  1     100     120     180 2019_12          2
2  2     300     350     200 2020_01          3
3  3      NA      NA     120 2020_01          3
4  4     430     400     240 2020_02          4
5  5     270     240     340 2019_12          2
```

I have tried for-loop with this function: `df["col_index"][i] = grep(df[["X"]][i], colnames(df))`

However when the row number is greater than 100k, the speed of this function is not efficient. Are there anyway better to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `match` to get the column index by matching the column names 2 to 4 and the column 'X'.  Add 1 to make corrections because we are matching from the 2nd to 4th column

```
df$col_index <- match(df$X, names(df)[2:4]) + 1
df
#  id 2019_12 2020_01 2020_02       X col_index
#1  1     110     120     180 2019_12         2
#2  2      90     350     200 2020_01         3
#3  3     200      NA     120 2020_01         3
#4  4     330     400     240 2020_02         4
#5  5     250     240     340 2019_12         2
```

It would also work with the full column names

```
match(df$X, names(df))
```